# android, xmlns, No resource indentifier error

Tags: android-layout, facebook-android-sdk

In an xml layout file, the xmlns is already defined, but I get this error at compile time: No resource identifier found for attribute. Why is that? thanks

I'm following a Facebook dev tutorial on facebook site https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/ the layout file is as follows:

```
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
            android:id="@+id/profilepic"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:preset_size="large" app:is_cropped="true"
    />
   </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, have to replace `/res-auto` with `res/com.facebook.samples.profilepicture`

Answer (score 0):

Your layout file looks correct. check that in your 'project.properties' file, the 'android.library.reference.1' value points to the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

The res-auto is feature properly supported in API level 17. It must be applied for all layouts using custom attributes. It is automatically replaced on build time, by eclipse.

Ref [Updated SDK Tools and ADT revision 17](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/03/updated-sdk-tools-and-adt-revision-17.html)